# Django Model set @property with filter and show it on template

Tags: python, django

I have case that need to count and show user that doesn't have a blog.

here my `views.py`

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')

    @property
    def DOESN_HAVE_BLOG(self):
        blog = Self.Blog.all().values_list('user', flat=True)
        value = Self.User.exclude(id__in=blog)
        return value
```

here `mytemplate.html`

```
{{ DOESN_HAVE_BLOG.count }}
```

but its doesn't work

Comment: Why do you think you can get away without using an instance of `Blog`?

Comment: iam noob, can you explain?

Comment: Which view are you using? Generic ListView / DetailView or a regular view where model instance (blog) is explicitly passed to context?

Comment: iam using CBV (ListView)

Comment: Please explain each line, it's true that your code contains a lot of stuff that should not be done like that, but by explaining what you want to do in each line maybe we will help you. let's start by this `blog = Self.Blog.all().values_list('user', flat=True)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that you would do as a model property. A property relates to an actual instance of Blog, but you are looking for Employees that have *no* instances at all.

Instead, you should do the query separately in the view - a good place for this is in `get_context_data`.

```
class MyView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        data['DOESN_HAVE_BLOG'] = Employee.objects.filter(blog=None)
        return data
```

Comment: can have multiple `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
` for my views?... since my views alreay have `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
`

Comment: No, you should put all the logic into one method.

Comment: What is better to use: `blog = None` or `blog__isnull = True`?

Comment: They are the same.